# Nunit: Can you open multiple projects in unit using a bat file?

Tags: nunit

I currently used a batch file which runs a project of mine which is simlar to the following:

```
nunit-gui.exe nunit.tests.csproj
```

Can it be setup to use two or more project files? I've tried adding quote marks and seperating the project names with commas and semi-colons but no luck.

Will I just have to create a master solution with all tests in and send that through as the parameter instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use NUnit project files. In the "config" section you can specify any number of assemblies to load.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run these by running a batch file? If so I think that nunit-console.exe or nunit-console-86.exe

Then to run multiple items its normally

nunit-console assem1.dll assem2.dll assem3.dll

I haven't tried it with project files but should work the same

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5.2